# Sprocket upgrade needed to upgrade Stihl MS260 chainsaw from 0.325 to a 3/8 bar and chain?

Tags: landscaping, tools, chainsaw

I got a Stihl MS260 as a present that came with a 12"(0.325) bar guide and chain setup.
I would like to upgrade it to 18"(3/8).
Will this upgrade require a sprocket change?

Chainsaw-modding noob here, please educate me! I'm a little confused with the information available in the interwebs. Thank you!

Comment: You may get a better answer on https://diy.stackexchange.com/ . They have many chainsaw modding questions there.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to an 18 inch bar.

If you want to change **pitch** (chain link length between rivets) from 0.325 to 0.375 (3/8") you **will need a new sprocket** of that pitch as well. Think "gears not meshing" for a mismatch of chain and sprocket pitch.

Or you could go 18" and 0.325 and not need a sprocket change.

When I search for MS260 bars, the [Stihl site comes up with nothing](https://www.stihlusa.com/products/product-selector/guide-bar-and-chain-selector/), *well, one vague option that's not available*, oddly, and other sites offer 16, 18, 20 and 24 inches, all in 0.325 pitch.

As far as I can make out from [the manual that comes up only in German](https://static.stihl.com/api/BaOnline/Download/ZBA0458-172-0021%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2007ZBA/0458-172-0021_ZBA_07_02.pdf?_gl=1*tir8u8*_ga*MjAzMzI1NTUwNC4xNzAwMjMyNTg0*_gid*MTc5ODEwNTUuMTcwMDIzMjYyNg..), .325, .404, 3/8 and 1/4 are all supported pitches.

[This arborist site discussion](https://www.arboristsite.com/threads/ms-260-chain-and-bar-suggestions.334880/) mostly suggests sticking to 0.325 (it's not a particularly big motor. 3/8 chain cuts more wood into sawdust, making more work for the motor.) 3/8 (0.375) is the pitch being longer than 0.325, but it comes with a wider chisel tooth and thicker chain, so more kerf, meaning more sawdust per cut.

Comment: That utterly useless bar/chain selector tool also comes up with nothing useful for my saw. Which came with an 18" bar...

Answer (score 2):

I had to check before I replied.  The MS260 is available with 18inch bar guide. I was worried that you might be overloading the motor.

I don't know about this model, but I had a much larger beast and it didn't require a sprocket change when I went for a larger bar guide.

You could email/phone/visit a Stihl agent and ask that question, if you want to be 100% sure.